# How to calculate FPS in my empty game?

Tags: java, android, game-engine, frame-rate, game-loop

To create the game loop I followed [this excellent tutorial](http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/). But I thought the next tutorial on displaying the FPS was a little iffy so I tried going solo. I'm reasonably confident in the `trackFps()` method I made; it's called after calculating the time difference between frames, measures predicted FPS everytime it runs, stores those predicted FPS values in an `ArrayList`, then once a second has passed adds up those predicted FPS and divides by the number of values added to get an average FPS.

When I run through it with the debugger it functions fine, but when I run through it normally I get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 6
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
at biz.hireholly.engine.GameLoop.trackFps(GameLoop.java:120)
at biz.hireholly.engine.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:73)
```

It's pretty explanatory and occurs on this line `fps += fpsStore.get(fpsTrackCount-1);`. But I can't see how the `fpsTrackCount` Variable could be getting as high as 26, it should only be as high as the number of variable's stored in the `ArrayList` `fpsStore`.

Would someone look through my `GameLoop` class, in particular the `trackFps()` method at the bottom? I'll provide the whole thing. It's heavily commented but there's not much to it and should be very familiar for some of you.

`GameLoop` (contains the `trackFps()` method for calculating FPS at the bottom):

```
package biz.hireholly.engine;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * The GameLoop is a thread that will ensure updating and drawing is done at set intervals.
 * The thread will sleep when it has updated/rendered quicker than needed to reach the desired fps.
 * The loop is designed to skip drawing if the update/draw cycle is taking to long, up to a MAX_FRAME_SKIPS.
 * The Canvas object is created and managed to some extent in the game loop,
 * this is so that we can prevent multiple objects trying to draw to it simultaneously.
 * Note that the gameloop has a reference to the gameview and vice versa.
 */

public class GameLoop extends Thread {

    private static final String TAG = GameLoop.class.getSimpleName();
    //desired frames per second
    private final static int MAX_FPS = 30;
    //maximum number of drawn frames to be skipped if drawing took too long last cycle
    private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
    //ideal time taken to update & draw
    private final static int CYCLE_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    //the gameview actually handles inputs and draws to the surface
    private GameView gameview;

    private boolean running;
    private long beginTime = 0; // time when cycle began
    private long timeDifference = 0; // time it took for the cycle to execute
    private int sleepTime = 0; // milliseconds to sleep (<0 if drawing behind schedule) 
    private int framesSkipped = 0; // number of render frames skipped

    private double lastFps = 0; //The last FPS tracked, the number displayed onscreen
    private int fpsTrackCount = 1; // number we'll divide the fpsSTore by to get average
    private ArrayList<Double> fpsStore = new ArrayList<Double>(); //For the previous fps values
    private long lastTimeFpsCalculated = System.currentTimeMillis(); //used in trackFps

    public GameLoop(SurfaceHolder holder, GameView gameview) {
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = holder;
        this.gameview = gameview;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;     
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){

        Canvas c;

        while (running) {
            c = null;
            //try locking canvas, so only we can edit pixels on surface
            try{
                c = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                //sync so nothing else can modify while were using it
                synchronized (surfaceHolder){ 

                    beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    framesSkipped = 0; //reset frame skips

                    this.gameview.update();
                    this.gameview.draw(c);

                    //calculate how long cycle took
                    timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                    //good time to trackFps?
                    trackFps();

                    //calculate potential sleep time
                    sleepTime = (int)(CYCLE_PERIOD - timeDifference);

                    //sleep for remaining cycle
                    if (sleepTime >0){
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(sleepTime); //saves battery! :)
                        } catch (InterruptedException e){}
                    }
                    //if sleepTime negative then we're running behind
                    while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS){
                        //update without rendering to catch up
                        this.gameview.update();
                        //skip as many frame renders as needed to get back into
                        //positive sleepTime and continue as normal
                        sleepTime += CYCLE_PERIOD;
                        framesSkipped++;
                    }

                }

            } finally{
                //finally executes regardless of exception, 
                //so surface is not left in an inconsistent state
                if (c != null){
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /* Calculates the average fps every second */
    private void trackFps(){
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(timeDifference != 0){
            fpsStore.add((double)(1000 / timeDifference));
        }
        //If a second has past since last time average was calculated,
        // it's time to calculate a new average fps to display
        if ((currentTime - 1000) > lastTimeFpsCalculated){
            int fps = 0;
            int toDivideBy = fpsTrackCount;
            while ((fpsStore !=  null) && (fpsTrackCount > 0 )){
                fps += fpsStore.get(fpsTrackCount-1);
                fpsTrackCount--;
            }
            lastFps = fps / toDivideBy;
            lastTimeFpsCalculated = System.currentTimeMillis();
            fpsTrackCount = 1;
            fpsStore.clear();
        }
        else{   
        fpsTrackCount++;
        }
    }
    /* So That it can be drawn in the gameview */
    public String getFps() {
        return String.valueOf(lastFps);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see calls to your TextDrawable, can you post the code where you use it to draw the FPS value? ah, found it.

Comment: Sorry yeah that was in the GameView i uploaded on Pastebin because i'd didn't want my question to get to cluttered.

Answer (score 2):

ok lets take at this first...

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 26, size is 6
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
at biz.hireholly.engine.GameLoop.trackFps(GameLoop.java:120)
```

so somewhere in trackFPS a get() is absurdly out of bounds...

```
private void trackFps()
{
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(timeDifference != 0)
    {
        fpsStore.add((double)(1000 / timeDifference));
    }
    //If a second has past since last time average was calculated,
    // it's time to calculate a new average fps to display
    if ((currentTime - 1000) > lastTimeFpsCalculated)
    {
        int fps = 0;
        int toDivideBy = fpsTrackCount;
        while ((fpsStore !=  null || !fpsStore.isEmpty()) && (fpsTrackCount > 0 ) && (fpsTrackCount < fpsStore.getCount()))
        {
            //synchronized(this) {
            fps += fpsStore.get(fpsTrackCount-1);
            fpsStore.remove(fpsTrackCount-1);  //otherwise we'll get stuck because of getCount condition
            fpsTrackCount--;
            //}
        }
        lastFps = fps / toDivideBy;
        lastTimeFpsCalculated = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //fpsTrackCount = 1;
        //fpsStore.clear();
        Log.d("trackFPS()", "fpsTrackCount = "+fpsTrackCount+"\tfpsStore.size() = "+fpsStore.size()+"\t"+fpsStore.toString());
    }
    else   
        fpsTrackCount++;
}
```

give this a spin. if it doesn't perform too well, try uncommenting the sync'd block.

as far as your other problem, concerning the TextDrawable, I had a look at your GameView...

here's what i foudn in SurfaceChanged()

```
  fps = new TextDrawable();
  fps.setText("HELLO");
```

now, why don't you move that to SurfaceCreated()? maybe you're getting alot of surfaceChanged() callbacks but aren't aware of it since you have no Logcat calls? :) it's the only place where the TextDrawable is being instantiated from what i can see.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time! First Here's the result of the log, not really what i'd want it to be priniting http://i.imgur.com/D2sG7.jpg . I think the line `fpsTrackCount =1` should probably still be left in. When i un-commented it though log output wasnt much better, it only ever displayed an fpsTrackCount of 1 and the fpsStore still had the numbers 500 and 1000 in it as in the image above. Good point about moving the intialisation bit to SurfaceCreated but i'm afraid i still see a blur of overlapped numbers on screen so im not sure thats the cause. Appreciating your help!

Comment: also .getCount() wasn't recognised, i think it should be .size() ?

Comment: yes :) size()... as for the TextDrawable, maybe something like this...
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

i've slightly editted.

Comment: Thanks to your comment it just occurred to me that a simple `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` before drawing anything else would clear the screen just fine, so if thats an okay way to go about it then that's one problem solved!

Comment: one down, one to go. so, can you post some logcat output of the new log? the one that logs fpsTrackCount and fpsStore.size() side-by-side?

Comment: *note i moved the log bit to before the while clause because i realised you'd probably want to expect the contents before removals? This is what it looks like with `fpsTrackCount = 1;` commented out: http://i.imgur.com/ngZ3h.png . it look almost the same as when the log is in the position you suggested above. When i run through with the debugger the fpsStore has more meaningful values.. (149, 300 ect)

Comment: good thinking ;) but looks like you missed the edit where   Log.d("trackFPS()", "fpsTrackCount = "+fpsTrackCount+"\tfpsStore.size() = "+fpsStore.size()+"\t"+fpsStore.toString());

Comment: whoopsie here you go http://i.imgur.com/6GZUk.png ... Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: This doesn't look good. fpsStore keeps on inflating even though we clear it after every averaging; moreover fpsTrackCount is 'bigger' than fpsStore ... have you considered using System.nanoTime() in trackFPS() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use apps in the android play store for measuring FPS. A very good app that has been recently published is GameBench. It not only captures FPS, but also screenshots so you can understand what was going on when FPS drops. It also provides CPU Usage and in some devices GPU Usage too. I am sure you will find it useful.

Link is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamebench.metricscollector)

Answer (score -3):

I think this code should be working for you

```
cputhrottle=(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
cputhrottle = (int)System.currentTimeMillis() - cputhrottle;cputhrottle=33-cputhrottle;
```

its 30 frames per second it will be useful to you

Comment: Sorry but this answers going to need some more explaination and while it's relevant i'm not sure it's really in answer to my question at all.